# How to store a dynamically typed variable in a Rust struct?

Tags: rust, compiler-construction

I disclaim that I'm a beginner in Rust and this is my first project. I'm trying to code a SQL compiler in Rust. I have to create a `Token` struct that represents a syntactical unit of a SQL query. In C/C++ I would write a structure like this:

```cpp
typedef unsigned long Value;

// Represents the type of the token (e.g. number, string, identifier...)
typedef enum class TokenType { ... }

struct Token {
  TokenType type;
  unsigned char priority;
  Value value;
}
```

Using this approach I use the `Value` type to store any kind of value. If it's a number, `value` is interpreted as an integer, float..., whereas when `value` represents a string or an identifier, it is cast to a string pointer and then used to access the heap-allocated data it points to.
To decide how to handle the `value` property of `Token`, I use the `type` field. For example, if `type` tells me the token is an integer, I cast `value` to an int. If `type` tells me the token is an identifier, I cast `value` to a string pointer.

My question is, is it possible to do something similar in safe Rust? If not, then what would be a nice way of achieving a dynamically typed variable that can be interpreted in multiple ways based on the `TokenType`? Or is there a neater approach to creating a syntactical token that works well in Rust?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use generics, https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-struct-definitions

Comment: or enums too...

Comment: Even in C or C++, you should use a union instead of a cast in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust, where you have a closed set of possible types, you should use an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html). Enums in Rust are not like in C: they can carry payload (i.e. they're sum types).

```rust
enum TokenType {
    Number(i32),
    Identifier(String),
    String(String),
    Plus,
    Minus,
    // ...
}
```

And then `match` against it:

```rust
let e: TokenType = ...;
match e {
    TokenType::Number(n) => println!("number: {n}"),
    TokenType::String(s) => println!("string: {s}"),
    TokenType::Plus => println!("plus"),
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```rust
// some variants can hold parsed data
pub enum TokenKind {
    Ident,
    Op,
    Int(i64),
    Float(f64),
    String,
    Eof,
}

pub struct Source {
    pub content: String,
}

impl Source {
    // no need to allocate a new string for each token, just store the span
    // and access the slice when needed
    pub fn get_underlying_string(&self, token: &Token) -> &str {
        &self.content[token.span.clone()]
    }   
}

// we use struct because token has some common parts
pub struct Token {
    pub kind: TokenKind,
    pub span: Range<usize>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut token = Token {
        kind: TokenKind::Int(10),
        span: 0..1,
    };

    println!("int: {}", match token.kind {
        TokenKind::Int(i) => i,
        _ => panic!("unexpected token kind"),
    }); // prints "int: 10"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, there's a better solution for this problem.

Rust's `enum`s work a bit differently, but they are even more suited to this case: Enum variants can themselves have fields that only apply to one variant of the enum.

That way, you can store the value *inside* your enum:

```rust
struct Token{
  priority: u8,
  value: TokenValue
}

enum TokenValue{
  Int (i32),
  Str (String),
  Id {
    name: String,
    id: u32
  }
  // ... other variants
}
```

This also gives type safety the code that uses it, and Rust can optimise how much memory it allocates for each variant.

This feature is explained very well [in The Rust Programming Language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html).