# How to add a dynamic type field in Rust struct?

Tags: rust

I am trying to decode the base 64 url encoded JWT token using [jsonwebtoken crate](https://docs.rs/jsonwebtoken/latest/jsonwebtoken/fn.decode.html). I am getting type mismatch error on `amr` claim type which can be a string `amr:pwd` OR a sequence of string `amr:{pwd,mfa}`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Claims {
    aud: String,
    iss: String,
    iat: String,
    amr: Vec<u8>,
    scp: String
}

// In main
let bytes = URL_SAFE_NO_PAD.decode("ey.........").unwrap();
let ress = serde_json::from_slice::(&bytes);
```

The above works only when amr is a sequence of string and throws an error for just the string.

I am new to Rust and upon searching stackoverflow for related issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723848/how-to-store-a-dynamically-typed-variable-in-a-rust-struct). I thought I can do something like below:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Dynamic {
Str(String),
Vec(Vec<String>),
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Claims {
aud: String,
iss: String,
iat: String,
amr: Dynamic,
}
```

But the above throws an error : `Err(Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 528)`

Can anyone help out here as to how to define dynamic types in rust struct? Thanks

Comment: By "dynamic types" do you just mean `enum`?  The way Serde handles enum deserialization is different, it'll expect an intermediate key to understand which variant to use. You may need to write your own serialize/deserialize implementation to map to the one you need/prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you point me to some sample examples that I can look at for similar cases? All I want is for the decode function to return claims from the encoded  jwt token which sometimes contains a claim type amr as string and sometimes a sequence of strings.

Comment: While it can be a bit daunting at first, there are [examples in the documentation](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html). For something like this there's even [specific guidance](https://serde.rs/enum-number.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are so close, you only need to [untag](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#untagged) your `Dynamic` enum by adding a `#[serde(untagged)]` container attribute. Read more about enum representations [here](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html).

This should work:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Dynamic {
    Str(String),
    Vec(Vec<String>),
}
```

Here a small demo on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32f1865239e07fe4a36a57e3837f0804).